# Looking for "ACS + SOAP WCF Service Hosted in IIS" sample

Tags: wcf, acs

I've been trying to figure out how to host a SOAP WCF Service in IIS and protect it by ACS, but I keep running into problems with every single example I can find.  For instance, none of the standard ACS samples ([http://acs.codeplex.com](http://acs.codeplex.com/)) show how to do this.  Instead, the closest example shows how to self-host a WCF service but does not show how to host the service in IIS.  Other examples work fine but are either REST-oriented, or inexplicable or simply uncompileable.  I have researched this a lot but I am clearly getting nowhere.  What I really need is a detailed walthrough that works end-to-end.  Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it boils down to getting the web.config correct.  This is explained in the e-book http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28362 on page 145 and following.  You need to correctly configure the ws2007FederationHttpBinding on your web-service.